# how to use (after a pca) just one vector in an object?

Tags: r, pca

I feel like kind of a noop.....

Well I have a pca (I have used prcomp) and I am looking for the eigenvectors of the covaricance matrix.
I know I get those using rotation. rotation gives me a matrix composed of the eigenvectors.
But if I want to print (or use for any other purpose) only one of those eigenvectors: how do I call it? I know I can print all of them by using print (mypcqobject$rotation) but what if I only want one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would subset the $rotation object.  Which vector do you want?

```
> prcomp(USArrests, scale=T)$rotation[1,]    # Murder row
       PC1        PC2        PC3        PC4 
-0.5358995  0.4181809 -0.3412327  0.6492278 
> prcomp(USArrests, scale=T)$rotation[,1]    # PC1 column
    Murder    Assault   UrbanPop       Rape 
-0.5358995 -0.5831836 -0.2781909 -0.5434321
```

Comment: Do I geht it right that your first call of prcomp gives me the first row of the rotation while your second call gives me the first column?

Comment: Technically, it's the different index used on the (same) return value from prcomp, but you are correct.

Comment: ahm...any hints on how to google that? I always end up either on websites with tutorials which really start by explaining what is a loop (so, basics) or I get no results at all because "R" is part of so many things which have nothing to do with the language - for instance it is a short form for "Real numbers" -.- So I end up asking really idiotic questions here just because I find no other source.

Comment: Try adding the term 'stats' or 'language' or both to the search string.  That helps a lot.  Reading "Introduction to R" is also recommended.  You'll find that here:  cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf

Comment: In all honesty, my best recommendation would be to read http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf. Because what your question really boils down to is "how to extract the first column of a matrix". Nothing specific to PCA.